# Percentage of SA halacha per Mitzva breakdown?

Tags: halacha, mitzvah, statistics

Is there a study or depiction (similar to the [visualisations at Sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org/visualizations), although doesn't have to be a visualisation)  that takes the whole of the Shulchan Aruch and traces every single halacha back to which D'Oraita Mitzva it falls under (where applicable), and mapping out the modern halacha back to its roots?

I am very curious. I imagine that the vast majority of contemporary halacha probably derives from a small percentage of the Mitzvot that are still practiced today. I wonder if there is an 80/20 rule (pareto principle) or any other interesting correlations. I wonder if there are any Torah lessons that can be learned from doing this. I wonder if the 7 Mitzvot that are the 7 Noahide laws play a huge role?

---

Difficulties: I have laid out a pretty focused definition of what I want, so anything that fits within that is fine. The questions that come up are rabbinic mitzvot, decrees and fences. If there are *any* attempts to classify halacha like this, no matter how they solve the above, please bring them and that's a valid answer - i.e. I don't mind (there are probably many ways to solve that, and either way I will consider the information valuable) thank you.

I would even be happy to see a single statement that says "most of our contemporary halacha comes from these 16 mitzvot: ... ", if that statement is well sourced, but the more comprehensive the better of course.

Comment: What would you do with Chanukah [candles], Purim (reading the Megillah), fast days (especially Tisha be-Av), Netilat Yadyim and Eruvin? Their _obligation_ derives from the Mitzvah [to obey the High Court regarding all \[the ordinances\] they establish for Israel](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Positive_Mitzvot.174?lang=bi&lang2=en) (also [MT Mamrim 1:2](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Rebels.1.2?lang=bi&lang2=en)). But, the same can be said for many other halachot, more readily connected with other Mitzvot.

Comment: Somewhat related: "[Rambam's MT chapters without Biblical founding Mitzvhas](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/130415/1368)".

Comment: The Rambam connects halachos to the Taryag mitzvos. You could use Be'er Hagolah to trace halachos to Rambam.

Comment: So does all of Shabbat fall under one mitzva?

Comment: You're seeking according to the opinion of the Rambam? The best way would be to make a script connecting the Sefer HaMitzvos of the Rambam to his halachos in Mishneh Torah and then connecting them to where they appear in Shulchan Aruch. Shabsi Frankel has all of this cross referenced but it's not digitized...

Comment: Another good website is olamot.net

Comment: @TamirEvan Alright, it's not related. My apologies

Comment: "_I would even be happy to see a single statement that says ,most of our contemporary halacha comes from these 16 mitzvot_ ..." Not what you're looking for, but Rambam [at the end of the listing of the Mitzvot Aseh in his Sefer ha-Mitzvot](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sefer_HaMitzvot%2C_Conclusion_for_Positive_Commandments.2?vhe=Sefer_HaMitzvot,_Warsaw_1883&lang=bi&lang2=en) lists 60 Mitzvot Aseh that he calls הכרחיות (definite), that he says all normal men are obligated in, regardless of status or circumstances.