# Which Mitzva has the most Halachot?

Tags: halacha, mitzvah

In the spirit of [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/136949/percentage-of-sa-halacha-per-mitzva-breakdown), which Mitzva has the most halachot? If it is hard to pick one, happy to hear about a "top 5" etc.

E.g.

> It is hard to measure which Mitzva has the most halachot, as that's too loose a definition of how a Mitzva breaks down. However, it certainly seems that these Mitzvot X, Y and Z play a huge role in the Shulchan Aruch compared to other Mitzvot

would be a fine answer. Or even "there is no answer to this question, as there are many halachot for many Mitzvot and there are no clear outliers for *the most*"

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%97%D7%92%D7%99%D7%92%D7%94_%D7%90_%D7%97

Comment: Incidentally, Tractate Sabbath of the Babylonian Talmud is the largest in terms of number of words of the Germara despite Bava Bathra having the most pages..

Comment: @Grapefruit I think measuring how many Halachot a Mitzvah has by looking at the size of the tractate, won't necessarily be accurate. Due to the fact that a tractate contains much more than the Halachot pertaining to that particular subject. Personally looking in the rambam would be a much better place to start.

Comment: Why doesnt Shabbos win? It has 39 melachos and each one is a world of its own.

Comment: Shabbos,nedarim, korbanos , eruvin ,sukka